# Usage of 'half' as an adverb?

Tags: word-usage

Let's say I am with my friend, I want to tell him to not to finish pizza straightaway

Can I say,

> **Eat it(pizza) half**, save something for tonight's game.

or

> **Pour juice half** in cup1 and other half in cup2.

Comment: You can say "Eat half of it" and "Pour half the juice."

Comment: Either you eat or you don't. Either you pour or you don't. You can't half eat. You can't half pour. You can, however, eat half *of* something or pour half *of* something.

Comment: @David: I'm not entirely sure whether over 32000 instances of ["can't half eat"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22can't+half+eat%22&oq=%22can't+half+eat%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.11274j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) supports or gives the lie to that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, OP's specific examples aren't valid English.

There aren't many contexts where ***half*** can be used adverbially. I think they're all a bit informal or idiomatic. For example:

> *It was so difficult I half thought of giving up.*
>    *I don't half like this question!*
>    *The time is half past four.*

Arguably that last one is actually *adjectival*. Off-hand, I think *all* other "adverbial" usages will carry the sense of *to a certain extent, in some degree*, rather than a literal "splitting into two parts".